# Hide activerecord objects of a given status from all scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In a `Post` model with many different scopes(by date interval, by author or content, sum of total posts), the model contains a `status` attribute, where if given a status of `:hidden` it would then be excluded from all scopes(e.g. sum of total posts scope would return total posts where status is different than hidden ), is there a 'DRYer' way to do this instead of adding something like `where status!=hidden` to each scope?

Comment: Create a `hidden` scope and add `hidden` to each scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
default_scope { where.not(status: :hidden) }
```

It's not set in steel, the default scope is still a scope and can be removed with `unscoped` if you ever need to bypass this condition:

```
scope :hidden { unscoped.where(status: :hidden) }
```

[Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#applying-a-default-scope)

Comment: This is a bad solution as it will make it impossible to ever search for any Post that is hidden.  In general, `default_scope` should be avoided at all cost.

Comment: @tagCincy wrong. If you need to bypass this, do an `unscope`. It's a question of whether it's easier to write `.hidden` everywhere, or write `.unscope` a bunch of times. I should reflect this in the answer however, thanks for mentioning the potential pitfall.

Comment: Implicit programming is bad.  Your solution to add a default_scope to EVERY query against that model to solve a problem on 3 queries.

Comment: *Implicit programming is bad.* -- it's an opinion. If there are like 20 queries and 15 of these need that condition, it's worth making it apply by default to just write less code and make less potential mistakes. And it's kinda weird to hear that in regards to a framework that uses "convention over configuration" and thus contains tons of implicit programming.

Comment: @tagCincy, see comment above. I don't mind downvotes though, I just don't think enough information is given to judge if it's good or bad, leave that to the question's author, he asked for that. This is a most direct way to accomplish this in Rails.

Comment: You are correct, if that scope needs to be run on all queries, save a handful, then yes, that might be a good use case for `default_scope`.  However, the OP listed only 3 queries that need the scope, therefore your solution of immediately going to a `default_scope` is impractical and not strong advice to a novice.

Comment: @tagCincy those were examples, we have no idea if there are three or more or how the amount of queries will evolve. I assume the author is sane and knows what he's asking for.

Comment: I understand that this might be a bad solution given the implicit programming problem, but it is pretty much what I was looking for, as noted by @D-side I only gave 3 examples but this idea is for a very high number of queries and one would display hidden objects.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a "parent scope":

```
scope :hidden, -> { where(status: :hidden) }
```

then in the scopes that you want to filter hidden, prepend it to the `where`:

```
scope :foo, -> { hidden.where(foo: :bar) }
```